# Алгоритм поиска количества известных слагаемых

Tags: java, c#, c++, алгоритм

Есть круг разделен на 16 секторов.Каждый сектор разделен на 10 сегментов.

В секторе 11 сегменте 7 сидит лягушка, которая прыгает: 1) прямо на 3, или на 2 прямо и 1 в влево, или 2 прямо и 1 вправо, или на 1 прямо и 2 в влево, или на 1 прямо и 2 вправо. Она должна допригнуты до 9 сектора 10 сегмента.

Есть две елки на круге на которые она не может прыгнуть.1 елка - сектор 14 сегмент 9, 2 - сектор 5 сегмент 8.

Надо найти минимальное количество прыжков, за которые лягушка достанется в сектор 9 сегмента 10

Лягушка может прыгать только по часовой стрелке. Через центр не может.

За круг также не может выпрыгнуть. Длина прыжка измеряется в секторах и сегментах.

Если прижок 3.0, это значит, что она прыгает на 3 сектора в перед (прямо), если 2.1 - это значит, что на 2 сектора вперед и сместилась на 1 позицию влево к краю круга (была - 11.7 стала 13.9) .если 2. -1 то 13.6(сместилась к центру)

У меня есть пять пар чисел {3,0},{2,1},{2,-1},{1,2},{1,-2}.

Эти пары чисел можно добавлять, например,
так: `3, 0 + 2,1 = 5,1`
или так: `3.0 + 3.0 + 2.1 + 1,2 = 9.3`
или так: `3.0 + 2.1 + 1.2 + 2.(- 1) = 8.2`.

Надо составить алгоритм, чтобы найти минимальное количество этих пар чисел (и сами пары), сумма которых будет 14.3.

Comment: Кароч.Привожу полное описание задачи.есть круг разделен на 16 секторов.Каждый сектор разделен на 10 сегментов.В секторе 11 сегменте 7 сидит лягушка, которая прыгает: 1) прямо на 3, или на 2 прямо и 1 в влево / вправо, или на 1 прямо и 2 в влево / вправо. Она должна допригнуты до 9 сектора 10 сегмента.Есть две елки на круге на которые она не может прыгнуть.1 елка - сектор 14 сегмент 9, 2 - сектор 5 сегмент 8.Надо найти минимальное количество прыжков, за которые лягушка достанется в сектор 9 сегмента 10.

Comment: Поясните, влево\вправо это значит на противоположную сторону круга? В чем указана длина прыжка, в сегментах?

Comment: Лягушка может прыгать только по часовой стрелке. через центр не может. За круг также не может выпрыгнуть. Длина прыжка измеряется в секторах и сегментах. Если прижок 3.0, это значит, что она прыгает на 3 сектора в перед (прямо), если 2.1 - это значит, что на 2 сектора вперед и сместилась на 1 позицию влево к краю круга (была - 11.7 стала 13.9) .если 2. -1 то 13.6(сместилась к центру).

Comment: А влево\вправо чтобы елку обходить, зачем тогда в бок на два хода двигаться?

Comment: И еще, хорошо бы все эти условия в вопрос поместить вместе с вашим решением.

Comment: Нууу,так написаны условия.Наверное что бы можно было не зависеть от елок (если их будет больше), чтобы алгоритм был массовым.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Упаковка рюкзака, правда в странной форме.

Заводите двоичное число, в котором количество битов соответствует количеству ваших пар.

Затем, пишите функцию, которая будет смотреть на биты этого числа и набирать из пар результат. Если дошли до нужного результата - ура, если превысили или так и не достигли - увеличиваем наше двоичное число и повторяем еще раз.

Сложность брутфорса 2^N, так что если у вас не много пар - дерзайте.

Comment: Если это задача об упаковке рюкзака, то почему ты описываешь экспоненциальное решение вместо полиномиального?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что 
-я не очень доволен, когда у меня спрашивают о моих мотивах. Голос моего кота мне посоветовал так сделать, например.
-я сослался на задачу про рюкзак, желающие далее могут погуглить в википедии, копипастить сюда классический алгоритм смысла нет
-автор показал, что у него три с половиной пары. Тупой брутфорс работает быстро и решительно, реализуется также быстро и решительно, дебажится еще быстрее и еще решительнее. Так зачем мне полиномиальный алгоритм?

Comment: 1. При чтении ответа кажется, что перебор является решением задачи о рюкзаке, что не так. 2. Я не вижу как эту задачу привести к задаче о рюкзаке, поскольку надо набрать точное соответствие сумм.

Comment: @Qwertiy у задачи о рюкзаке есть огромное количество вариаций. Будем продолжать терминологические споры?

Comment: Я добавил комментарий к проблеме с полным описанием задачи. Я отнял сектора и сегменты чтобы узнать длину которую лягушка должна допрыгнуть и думал, что надо: стрибок1 * количество + прыжок 2 * количество .... стибок5 * количество = длина прямо (количество надо подбирать). Затем нужно сравнить  сошлись ли отклонения. Кароч я запутался остаточно. Можете Вы
объяснить пошагово как такую задачу можно решить? Я просто про рюкзак не слышал(((